# How to get developer Id required to access AOL APIs?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, aol

I want to work with AOL.com API.

For this purpose I need to get **client_id(developer Id)**.

But I cant find where and how can I get this ID,
I checked [this](https://identity.aol.com/documentation/start/oauth2/browser-integration) site but I didn't find anything.

Any idea how can I get **client_id(developer Id)** for AOL.com API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if the AOL Open Auth API has been discontinued. http://www.programmableweb.com/api/aol-open-auth http://www.programmableweb.com/api/aol-open-mail

All links that used to point to its documentation now point to the main aol.com website.

I also just called AOL and the technical support representative was unable to find any information at all on any developer APIs.

Comment: How the mighty have fallen.

Answer (score 1):

The API still exists but undocumented:

```
https://api.login.aol.com/oauth2/request_auth
?client_id=xxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.cloudsponge.com%2Fauth
&scope=openid+sdct-w+mail-w+sdps-r+sdpp-w+ycal-w
```